# How to redirect to another subdirectory with same name with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect my file in folder A to folder B with the same file name.
EG.
yourdomain.com/folderA/nosedigger.php
to
yourdomain.com/folderB/nosedigger.php

The .htaccess is at yourdomain.com/folderA/.htaccess.

I tried the following but it does not work like a charm. Need help. Totally have no clue what the codes in .htaccess really mean.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folderB/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /folderB/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect from foldera to folderb, you can use the following redirect above your other rules

```
RedirectMatch ^/foldera/(.*)$ /folderb/$1
```

Comment: Nice! That's a sexy piece of code :D Really need to understand htaccess codings. Thanks starkeen!

Answer (score 0):

this should be all you need:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /folderA/(.*) /folderB/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

maybe:

```
RewriteRule ^folderA(/.*)?$ folderB$1 [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: @OneNation added another option

Comment: Still doesn't. Am not sure why.

Comment: dagon op said the htaccess file is in foldera. you rule will work in root.htaccess but in foldera.htaccess it will return 404.

Comment: well i always but my .hacacess in root, makes the most sense